# Prometheus not running in browser

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, grafana, prometheus

I have installed and started prometheus in aws ec2 instance, but i'm unable to open the prometheus link in my browser. It says site can't be reached. I Would be glad if you could help me.

After using curl command, curl http://localhost:****/metrics
It is showing metrics..

curl http://localhost:****/graph
running fine in terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed this yourself already, then the ports for HTTP traffic are probably blocked for your ec2 instance. Have a look at their documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/) to change that.

Comment: On the same server I have installed grafana with port 3000 and its working fine, but unable to access prometheus with port 9090.

Comment: What response are you getting? In any case, do check that you have port 9090 exposed on the ec2 instance. I've just tested it now on a nano ec2 instance, but with the opposite: I can access prometheus on 9090 but not Grafana on 3000 because 3000 isn't exposed.

Comment: Yes, the configuration is totally correct. Even, when I did curl https://localhost:9090/metrics or /graph it is showing correct output.

Comment: doing curl on the host is not the same as hitting it from an external client like your browser, where the request is coming from your local IP. I strongly recommend you check the Inbound Rules for the security group associated to your ec2 instance and make sure port 9090 is opened for inbound requests.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, when you are creating EC2 go to network Settings - Click Edit button.

In below -- Add security Group -- Click  & add Three Security Group.

```
1. Type - Custom TCP    Protocal - TCP    Port range  9090    prometheus
2. Type - Custom TCP    Protocal - TCP    Port range  9100    nodeexporter
3. Type - Custom TCP    Protocal - TCP    Port range  9093    alertmanager
```

After Creating you can copy the ---- `publicip:9090`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
I later realised it was because of my Wifi operator. I switched the internet to my mobile's hotspot and it worked fine. So it's mostly a network/VPN issue.